# Itext 7 - Cannot get tab order of the field

Tags: itext, itext7

Is it possible to get the tab order of the PDF field with iText7?

You can define tab order in Acrobat but getting that tab order doesn't seem to be available in the iText7 library.

I'm writing an application that extracts the fields from the PDF file and wanted those fields to be sorted depending on the tab order defined from the PDF.

Answer (score 1):

The order of fields (or more to the point: of annotations) on a page is determined by the **Tabs** entry in the page dictionary. Its value is specified as:

> *(Optional; PDF 1.5)* A name specifying the tab order that shall be used for annotations on the page (see 12.5 "Annotations"). The possible values shall be *R* (row order), *C* (column order), and *S* (structure order). Beginning with PDF 2.0, the possible values also include *A* (annotations array order) and *W* (widget order). Annotations array order refers to the order of the annotation enumerated in the **Annots** entry of the Page dictionary (see "Table 31 — Entries in a page object"). Widget order means using the same array ordering but making two passes, the first only picking the widget annotations and the second picking all other annotations.

*(ISO 32000-2, Table 31 — Entries in a page object)*

To implement your task of extracting *fields to be sorted depending on the tab order defined from the PDF*, therefore, you have to read this value for the page in question and depending on it, analyze the annotation coordinates, the structure tree, or the annotation array accordingly.

By the way, for fields with multiple widgets this means that they also have multiple tab positions; thus, exporting the *fields to be sorted depending on the tab order defined from the PDF* may be impossible for some documents.

Comment: Thanks @mkl for your answer.  This doesn't seem like an easy task in iText7.  Other pdf libraries like iTextSharp.LGPLv2.Core, they have a method called GetTabOrder to easily get the tab order of the field.

Comment: What iText 2.x, 4.x, and 5.x returned in that method, is the correct order value in case of the value of **Tabs** being **A**. In case of any of the other possible **Tabs** values, that value likely is wrong. (Probably the annotations array order also was the default.)